# Tomcat session replication with DXA

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery, dxa, dxa-java

We are using DXA Java and are facing a strange problem. We have setup a tomcat cluster and all tomcat instances are configured with IIS as the front-end. We are using Oracle 12g as the content delivery database. Session attributes are not being replicated across various tomcat nodes. I know this sounds like a tomcat config issue, but the exact same config on a different tomcat cluster not using DXA is working fine. Below are the versions being used:

1. Tocmat 8
2. IIS 8.5
3. Java 1.7
4. DXA (pre-release version of Java DXA)
5. SDL Tridion 2013 SP1

I would appreciate if anyone can shed some light on this.